# How can I get DOM's activeElement using CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using the console from Firefox to apply some commands. I am also using this Wikipedia page as [a guinea pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Thus, I can put my mouse cursor on the "Search" box on the right corner and if I do:

```js
>> document.activeElement.placeholder
```

I get:

> "Search Wikipedia"

Ok. I would like to achieve the same thing using **CSS selectors**. For instance, I can do:

```
$$("h1")[0].textContent
```

Which returns:

```
"GNU Guix"
```

This CSS selector gets the textual content of the "h1" but how to get the **active element**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is **not** possible. If someone thinks this is possible, please, show how to do it.